# Make image visible on image with low brightness

Tags: html, css

I've got a background which needs to have a dark background like it's got a low brightness.

When I add my brightness to 80% it's perfect but then I also lose the brightness of my text which is overlayed and that decreases in brightness as well. Is there a way I can increase the brightness on the text?

```
background-image: url("https...);
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-size: cover;
padding: 100px;
filter: brightness(80%);
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case ::before or ::after is solution

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  filter: brightness(80%);
  background-image: url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41-SYJSrDgL.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><span>test<span></div>
```